# Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'. Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: angular

In app.component.ts-

```
`storedPosts : any[] = [];
 onPostAdded(post: any) {
 this.storedPosts.push(post);`
```

app.component.html-

```
`<app-post-list [posts]= "storedPosts"></app-post-list>`
```

Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Tried by changing the posts to any in another component:

```
`export class PostListComponent{

 @Input() posts: any[] = [];
 }`
```

The text is not displayed on the output page but posts are posted as empty posts

Comment: Update your question with complete code of `app.component.ts`

Comment: Well, maybe try `any` instead of `any[]` :) Also please try to provide more code to us.

Comment: ... don't use `any` in the first place, type your data.